# Win-Kex Kali WSL2 doesn't launch at all

Tags: windows-10, kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I tried installing Win-Kex on my WSL2 Kali, but it doesn't work.

What I tried:

```bsh
kex
kex --sl
kex --esm
kex -s
```

I tried reinstalling Kex 3 times. I tried installing dbus-x11. I tried removing the files in `$HOME/.vnc/`. I tried stopping and rerunning the xrdp service.
I tried killing, stopping, rerunning, restarting, reconfiguring and running Kex in any way that I found. I tried running Kex from different directories, including the startup one and /home/user. I tried cleaning the vncserver. I tried disabling the firewall. I tried running everything with `sudo`. I tried following every tutorial in the first page of result in Google and DuckDuckGo. Nothing worked.

The result is always the same, if I run `kex` or `kex -s` it says:

```
Win-KeX server sessions:

X DISPLAY #     RFB PORT #      PROCESS ID
:1              5901            10017

You can use the Win-KeX client to connect to any of these displays.
```

And just does nothing. If I do `kex --sl` or `kex --sl -s` it does nothing and just waits forever. If I abort, it spams the console with

````
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:```

Help would be very much appreciated.
````

Comment: One thing you *probably* did, but didn't mention -- Did you reboot *Windows* at any point in this troubleshooting or shutdown the WSL subsystem?  If not, try `wsl --shutdown` -- I've seen a bug where localhost forwarding breaks down in WSL, and a simple restart of the subsystem fixes it.  Not sure if that's what you are running into it, but before diving any deeper, I wanted to check the basics.

Comment: Come to think of it, even a Windows reboot won't take care of it if "Fast Restart" is enabled.  If you have that enabled (probably default), then try a `wsl --shutdown` anyway.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I did reboot, but I can try again if it would help. I always do `wsl --shutdown` in general

Answer (score -1):

Your `X-DISPLAY` is set to `:1`, it should be `:0`. Once I do it I'll paste my process and results I've had same thing but your post sparked a memory and I was like crap mine said `:1` as well. You have to change the `:1` value to a `:0` value to read the display right.

Comment: Hello, please clarify your 2nd "once I do it" sentence and how it's relevant here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).